# Return a variable from inside a block

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asynchronous, nsarray, objective-c-blocks

Below I have some code which should return an array, the response from the server happens in a block:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)getArray
{
    NSMutableDictionary* params =[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  @"pending", @"command",
                                  @"2" , @"userID",
                                  nil];

    [[API sharedInstance] commandWithParams:params
                               onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json) {
                                   //result returned


                                   if ([json objectForKey:@"error"]==nil) {
                                       NSMutableArray *res = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                                       [res addObject:@"1234"];

                                       RETURN HERE

                                   } else {
                                       //error
                                       [UIAlertView title:@"Error" withMessage:[json objectForKey:@"error"]];
                                   }

                               }];
}
```

After parsing the data and creating an array I want to return the array I have created for the `getArray` method call. So far, after hours of trying I have not had any luck, even with trying some suggestions from previous questions on stackoverflow. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you aware that the block is executed and most likely finished at a time where the method `getArray` is long finished and gone?

Comment: Don't name methods with a `get` prefix unless you are actually using return by reference (which you generally shouldn't be).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd create a method in somewhere in the class let's say `- (void)arrayFetched:(NSArray *)fetchedArray`.

Then you modify your code like this:

```
//...
if ([json objectForKey:@"error"]==nil) {
    __weak NSMutableArray *res = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [res addObject:@"1234"];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self arrayFetched:[res copy]];
    });
    //...
```

and then do want you want with the array in the `arrayFetched:` method.

Comment: @bbum actually, I forgot to add an `__weak` in front of the `NSMutableArray *res`. But then again not quite sure, if that is even necessary. To be honest I've got some catching up do to about blocks and memory management under `ARC`. Afaik the block retains the array until the block is dealloced, but I wasn't sure if it's passing ownership correctly to the `arrayFetched:` method.

Answer (score 3):

pass the block as a param to the function

```
- (NSMutableArray *)getArray:(void (^)(NSArray *))block {}
```

And then replace the RETURN HERE with `block(res);`